# I/O schedulers for normal harddisks

Tags: linux-kernel, hard-disk, io, scheduling

For me figuring out what is the best choice for I/O scheduler in kernel was a challenge. First I learned that it is subjective then it depends upon the filesystem you use.

**I know you should use `No-op` for Solid Sate Drives (SSDs) for sure.**

What I want to know is the best choice for normal (rotating) HDDs containing Ext4 and NTFS filesystems (MBR style).

And does GPT or MBR has any effect on the choice I make?

Comment: MRB or GPT is about the partition scheme. It is only relevant for a small part of the disk (the very few first sectors). The rest depends on the partitions you created and the filesystems on them. Not on the partition scheme. Thus part of your question is easy to answer: No,  GPT or MBR has no influence on this.

Comment: Also, may I suggest to change "normal disks" to "rotating disk", or 'normal classic disk with rotating platters' or whatever you prefer. Normal on its own is subjective and in a few years SSD is something else might just be considered normal.

Comment: Can you try and add a  bit more detail to your question? It's unclear what you're asking here. What "choice" are you referring to above with respect to solid state vs. a "normal" HDD?

Comment: @slm sir, I am asking which I/O schedulers is best suited for rotating HDD? feel free to edit my Q if it is unclear

Answer (score 5):

> I know you should use No-op for Solid Sate Drives or SSD s for sure.

Not necessarily. I don't know why people keep treating SSD's as some kind of special case where you don't need the benefits of other schedulers. Having rotating disks just means it's more important to have requests merged. Merging requests is just one thing that the scheduler does.

CFQ, Deadline, etc all do more than that. For instance, CFQ let's you give particular processes priority over others (via `ionice`) whereas Deadline gives you latency guarantees. Either of these can still be relevant for SSD's.

Getting rid of rotating discs just means your scheduler decision is probably going to be more about how you want to carve up the bandwidth to and from disk rather than just merging requests.

**EDIT:** I'll also point out that on my system merges can be turned off (regardless of the scheduler) using the `/sys/block/sdXX/queue/nomerges` tunable. Deadline also gives a tunable for disabling front merges.

> What I want to know is the best choice for normal (rotating) HDD containing ext4 and NTFS File systems. (MBR style).

Scheduler choice is probably not super dependent on the filesystem you're using. dentries and frequently used files end up in the filesystem cache anyways. Either way, none of the schedulers seem to have any features that would benefit one filesystem (XFS, ext3, ext4+extents, reiserfs, etc) over another.

NTFS tends to get heavily fragmented so a smaller `read_ahead_kb` is probably beneficial (you have to play around with it to see what works for you). Basically, if it's a heavily fragmented volume then pulling in the neighboring data is probably just going to choke the bandwidth that could have gone to a legitimate request.

And GPT/MBR don't impact this decision at all.

Comment: So what do you suggest CFQ or deadline? which one give better results?

Comment: Performance tuning involves changing the behavior of the system in ways that would be detrimental to others but work better for your workload. If something categorically provided better performance, the software would just do that thing and leave you alone about it. If some setting is generally beneficial then the maintainers are suppose to make that the default setting and leave you alone about it. So you'll have to tell us more about how you use the system so we know what to trim away and what to add to it.

Comment: For home users, CFQ is usually the way to go (which is why it's usually selected as the default scheduler if you were curious). If this is a server it's harder to give general advice until you tell me more about what you're running on and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: When we tuned our Servers, which are equipped with SSDs, and searched for the best scheduler, we chose deadline (unfortunately I don't know all the reasons anymore but I know an article we started our research with [this German Thomas Krenn article](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Linux_I/O_Scheduler)). What comes in should be written to disk quickly. Our Services running on these servers worked on average more than 20% faster. So for us deadline seemed to be a good choice, even though we did not compare service times using other schedulers.